# Google Datastore: Querying random entities with filter

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

currently I am trying to query for location entities, filtered by two range filters that restrict latitude and longitude to the current view.

The query is supposed to return a limited number of the entities in a random distribution. Querying as-it-is returns a set ordered by Latitude.

```
Location Entity: Latitude, Longitude, ...
```

My approach so far is the following: I introduced a randomKey property that is of type double and has a range [0...1]. I store it in the Datastore with each Location entity and try to sort by that property:

```
Location Entity: Latitude, Longitude, ..., randomKey
```

But after executing this query:

```
Query query = new Query("Location");
query.addSort("randomKey", Query.SortDirection.ASCENDING);
query.setFilter(latitudeRangeFilter);
query.setFilter(longitudeRangeFilter);
```

I get the a IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The first sort property must be the same as the property to which the inequality filter is applied.  In your query the first sort property is randkey but the inequality filter is on longitude
```

Can someone give me an advice on how to proceed? Is my approach right or is there a better way?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2):

Your query is not going to work because you specified inequality filters on two different properties. You may need to use a [GeoSpacial query](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/geosearch).

As for randomness, it may be easier to retrieve all entities within a specified range, and then choose randomly the number of results that you need.

If the number of locations is manageable, you may want to keep all of them in memcache as a list, instead of querying the datastore each time.Then you can iterate through that list to get your results, which will be very fast and incur no reading costs.

Comment: Thanks! Your Answer helped me a lot: Storing the coordinates as GeoSpacial type solved my issue automatically. By applying the Rectangle filter, I am getting a random distribution of Locations.

Comment: Anyways, this feature is just an alpha release, so I cannot use it on the app engine server / production. Do you have a idea how I could realize this without the GeoSpacial? I have a huuge set of data, 10k+, so I do not want to query all

Comment: 10k+ is a small dataset :)  If you store long, lat and ID, they will all easily fit into a single memcache entity. So this may be the cheapest solution: retrieve all and use (no queries) until memcache resets, which does not happen often.

Comment: I don't understand how a given rectangle gives you a random distribution. If randomness is built into the coordinates, then you don't need a random key.

Comment: If you want a region and don't want to use GeoSpatial why not consider using a geohash and then retrieve keys only and then random choose from the keys and get the entity.